# How to write BEM CSS without "Block" duplicate, nor even SASS support?

Tags: css, sass, bem

I have element:

```
<span class="bage--red">4</span>
```

I need to chasnge background color of this element `.bage` just adding prefix:

```
--red
--green
```

How to to this property?

Now browsers gets this as one class `bage--red`. not two

Comment: And why do you use `bage--red` as a class name? If you want to set two classes to one element use space between them `bage red`

Comment: Could I use this? `.bage --red {}`

Comment: Somewhere I have seen notation with `--`

Comment: Yes, that notation is from BEM (Block Element Modifier). It's one style of writing CSS. In your case it would be <span class="bage bage--red">4</span> and in your CSS: .bage--red {background-color: red;}

Comment: You do see that notation (often in code generated using SASS) and the idea is to show the functionality, component type, etc. But assigning two class values that each handle a different aspect of the CSS to combine and get the result you want is a sensible and efficient way to do it.

Comment: @OPV Despite the question was closed, you could give my answer a look, I think it'll clarify something, it seems to be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate it as 2 classes.

```html
<span class="bage --red">4</span>
```

And in CSS:

```css
.bage {
  font-size: 100px;
}
.bage.--red { // instead of .bage--red
  color: red;
}
.bage.--green {
  color: green;
}
```

---

I have read somewhere that someone called this as "custom BEM". I used it all the time, write shorter CSS code, even without SASS/SCSS. Like from [this example](https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#element-modifier-name) ***(Element in BEM)***, instead of:

```html
<div class="menu">
    ...
    <span class="menu__item menu__item_visible menu__item_type_radio"> ... </span>
</div>

.menu__item_visible {}
.menu__item_type_radio { color: blue; }
```

I would write:

```html
<div class="menu">
  ...
  <span class="__item __item_visible __item_type_radio"> ... </span>
</div>

.menu .__item_visible {}
.menu .__item_type_radio { color: blue; }
```

Or ***(Modifider BEM)***, instead of

```
<button class="btn btn--secondary"></button>

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
}

.btn--secondary {
  color: green;
}
```

is

```
<button class="btn --secondary"></button>

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
}

.btn.--secondary {
color: green;
}
```